# Web App HTML, JS + Google Apps Script: How to go back to my app after return in GAS?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, phonegap

I'm building a web app using HTML, CSS and JavaScript and using Google Spreadsheet as a database. I'm planning to use **PhoneGap** to turn my web app into a real app.

I was able to read from my Google Sheet, using the Google Visualization API, now I'm working about the writing options: I used a function set with **Google Apps Script**, inside the Google Spreadsheet and it works correctly.

This is how my app works and what I need:

> 1. I query my first Google Spreadsheet (Database)
> 2. If I cannot find what I need, I can make a request
> 3. I send the request: the action of the form send my data to the Google Apps Script code
> 4. The GAS writes my data in a second Google Spreadsheet (Register)
> 5. **The GAS should send me back to my page**
> 6. The page sends a feedback on screen

As you can understand by the bold point, I'm not able to go back to my webpages... I don't know if there's any method or function to do this. The only thing I found was using `ContentService`to make the page "write another form and send it using JavaScript", but I don't think is the best solution...

I'll post my code down here... hoping someone can help me

```
function doPost(e){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myID").getSheetByName('SheetName');
 var column = 1; 
 var colArray = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
 var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math, colArray);


  var id = maxi+1;
  var name = e.parameter['name'];
  var surname = e.parameter['surname'];
  var serial = e.parameter['serial'];
  var eMail = e.parameter['mail'];
  var text = e.parameter['text'];
  var area = e.parameter['area'];
  var date = new Date();
  var ans = ""
  var flag = "Work In Progress";

  var vals = [id, date, name, surname, serial, eMail, area, text, ans, flag];

  var sheetObj = sheet.appendRow(vals);

  // return ContentService.createTextOutput(someOutput);
```

On the return line I should go back to my web app/app but I can't find a way to do it. Someone can help me or give me some advice?

Thanks a lot for your help!

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to your problem.

Instead of using `return ContentService.createTextOutput(someOutput);`

use `HtmlService` to return to your form

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('redirect').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

And your HTML file should look like this,

**Update:** `redirect.html` should be in the same project as that of your app script file.

`redirect.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>This Is A Sample Title</title>
<script>
function test()
{
    window.location.href = "www.hostname.com";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="test()">
Login
</body>
</html>
```

See if this works for you.

Comment: Just to be sure, the `redirect.html` file has to be in the same project of GAS, and it will point to my page, right?

Comment: The code show me the page (I can see "Login") but the `test()` function is not working... I tried even with `window.location.replace` but nothing...

Comment: Did you replace `www.hostname.com` with your form url?

Comment: It works! He just needed the whole address with `https` protocol.

Comment: Just a problem: when it reloads my page, the address is the one of my Google Script and the page is loaded not in mobile version but in the custom one...

Comment: do you know if there's a way to use GAS codes in a custom page I create such as calling the API? In this way I could run the code in my site and make it do what I need

Comment: That's not possible

Comment: Do you know if there's a way [to use Google Sheets API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414627/how-to-use-javascript-and-google-sheets-api-to-write-in-a-spreadsheet) to write the sheet via JavaScript without using GAS?

Comment: Checkout this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js)

Comment: I read a lot but I still cannot get if I can use the node.js library to follow the JavaScript example and use all of this with PhoneGap... do you know something about this?